# Foundation for Wordpress - How to show text if no menu is chosen?

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

### **Situation:**

1. I'm working with the wordpress theme "Foundation for Wordpress" by Drew Morris.
   [Link to theme](https://github.com/drewsymo/Foundation)
2. I've changed the standard structure for the top-bar and implemented the use of wordpress' menus like so:
   [image]

### **Goal:**

If no menu is assigned I'd like to display the text:

"Please assign a menu (Go to Design -> Menus -> Left/Right menu)"

### **Problem:**

It seems like there is a fallback for that situation already in place.

If no menu is assigned the standard wordpress navigation is chosen. 
How do I chage that?

### **Code:**

**Navigation menus are registered like so:**

**functions.php**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'foundation_menus' ) ) :


function foundation_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'left-menu' => __( 'Left Menu', 'foundation' ),
            'header-menu' => __( 'Right Menu', 'foundation' )
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'init', 'foundation_menus' );

endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'foundation_page_menu' ) ) :

function foundation_page_menu() {

    $args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'menu_class'  => 'large-12 columns',
    'include'     => '',
    'exclude'     => '',
    'echo'        => true,
    'show_home'   => false,
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after'  => ''
    );

    wp_page_menu($args);

}

endif;
```

**Menus are integrated in the theme like so:**

**header.php**

```
<nav class="top-bar">
            <ul class="title-area">
                    <li class="name"><h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1></li>
                    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'left-menu', 'menu_class' => 'left', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => 'foundation_page_menu', 'walker' => new foundation_navigation() ) ); ?>
            </section>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'menu_class' => 'right', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => 'foundation_page_menu', 'walker' => new foundation_navigation() ) ); ?>
            </section>
        </nav>
```

### Live-site

See it live over here: [Link to Live-Site](http://kanido-workspace.de/foundation/)

### Closing words

I'm no php professional, so I am grateful for any kind of help I can get.
Thank you for your support.

Best wishes from germany. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a rather simple way is using the `has_nav_menu` argument

in your case:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'left-menu' ) ) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'left-menu', 'menu_class' => 'left', 'container' => '', 'walker' => new foundation_navigation() ) );
}else{echo 'YOUR TEXT';}  ?>
```

and so on...

more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu)

Comment: Hey Mattias, awesome! Exactely what I was looking for. Not too complicated after all :-) Thanks!